# Furnace wont' ignite when turn on heat

Tags: furnace

I have a Nordyne AC/Gas Furnace single stage unit. The model number is c7bam03036c-b. The AC works very well in summer time. Now it's getting cold. I turned to heat. There is no air blowing out. So I checked the unit the gas is not ignited. The fan is not running. I checked the wiring at the thermostat and in the unit it seems correct. I get 27V at R wire. All other wires has no reading. The status indicator in the unit is normal, green and red lights are on and not blinking. What else can I check?

Comment: If you jumper R and W, does the unit fire up?

Comment: Thanks for looking at it.I will try tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: My Carrier natural gas furnace has an electric "glow" igniter; others have a spark ignition. I have had to replace by glow igniter once in the 26-year service life of my furnace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be getting 24-volts +- back from the thermostat to the furnace on the white wire.  If you are not getting this, the thermostat in not really calling for heat. Jumper from the red wire on your furnace to the white wire at the furnace.  the furnace should start.  This is fairly technical stuff. You may want to consult a pro.

Comment: It turns out to be a wiring issue. The guy installed the unit din't even connect the white wire at all. thanks all.